# Load assembly and start it as process

Tags: powershell, process, .net-assembly

How to start assembly (exe) as temporary process/thread, and then stop process when task finished? Desirable but not required with output to command line.
When running just an .exe in command line, all works correctly, but when starting in powershell, program works, but not correctly.

```
$Path = "c:\task.exe"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Path)
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)
$entryPointMethod = $assembly.GetTypes().Where({ $_.Name -eq 'Program' }, 'First').GetMethod('Main', [Reflection.BindingFlags] 'Static, Public, NonPublic')
$entryPointMethod.Invoke($null, (, [string[]] ('--archive')))
```

Part of c# code:

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
public static extern int CoInitializeSecurity(
    IntPtr pSecDesc,
    int cAuthSvc,
    IntPtr asAuthSvc,
    IntPtr pReserved1,
    AuthnLevel dwAuthnLevel,
    ImpLevel dwImpLevel,
    IntPtr pAuthList,
    EOLE_AUTHENTICATION_CAPABILITIES dwCapabilities,
    IntPtr pReserved3
);
```

hr returns not 0, when running it as assembly in powershell:

```
int hr = Methods.CoInitializeSecurity(IntPtr.Zero, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, Methods.AuthnLevel.RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CONNECT, Methods.ImpLevel.RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL, IntPtr.Zero, Methods.EOLE_AUTHENTICATION.EOAC_DYNAMIC, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: "program works, but not correctly." - are you gonna describe the ways in which it behaves unexpectedly, or are you waiting for us to guess it? :)

Comment: No problem, part of code attached.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Return value 0 = Success

Comment: Sorry, i had misstake. hr returns not 0.

Comment: So what does it return?